# Scraping websites with Scrapy

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

I have a code.

```
import scrapy
import requests



class cvbankas(scrapy.Spider):
    name ='bankas'
    allowed_domains =['cvbankas.lt']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cvbankas.lt/']

    def parse(self,response):        
        job_position_tag = response.css("h3.list_h3::text").extract()
        city_tag = response.css("span.list_city::text").extract()
        company_tag = response.css("span.dib.mt5::text").extract()
        salary_tag = response.css("span.salary_amount::text").extract()



        for item in zip(job_position_tag,city_tag,company_tag,salary_tag):
            scraped_info={
                'company':company_tag,
                'city': city_tag,
                'position': job_position_tag,
                'salary': salary_tag,
            }

            yield scraped_info
        
        next_page = response.css('li > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

And I don't know why it scrapes only 3 pages

[Output marked in red is only 3 pages of 88](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyWd3.png)

where's the problem in pagination?

Comment: Can you please insert the code as code, not as an image. In order to help you, we need to test your code and we don't want to retype it.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I fixed and you can test my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector was finding the first `<a>` tag he could find, which was the language `<a>` tag. You were changing languages not pages.

```
import scrapy
import requests



class cvbankas(scrapy.Spider):
    name ='bankas'
    allowed_domains =['cvbankas.lt']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cvbankas.lt/']

    def parse(self,response):        
        job_position_tag = response.css("h3.list_h3::text").extract()
        city_tag = response.css("span.list_city::text").extract()
        company_tag = response.css("span.dib.mt5::text").extract()
        salary_tag = response.css("span.salary_amount::text").extract()



        for item in zip(job_position_tag,city_tag,company_tag,salary_tag):
            scraped_info={
                'company':company_tag,
                'city': city_tag,
                'position': job_position_tag,
                'salary': salary_tag,
            }
            yield scraped_info
            
        
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="prev_next"]/@href').extract()[-1]
        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never thought that it's possible to use css and xpath at the same code. Appreciate for help ;)

Comment: @TomasVaitkus then upvote my answer if it had helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the website that you are scraping uses the url format `uri?page=x`
a simple loop to replace x can solve your problems.